# como encontrar os índices de um item que se repete em uma lista no Python

Tags: python, lista, índices, append

tenho uma *lista* `l = [1,6,6,2,3,6]` e quero formar outra com todos os *índices* do elemento `6`. No caso, a segunda lista deveria ser `l2 = [1,2,5]`, no entanto, quando tento usar o `l.index(6)`, a saída é só o primeiro índice.

Entrada:

```
l = [1,6,6,2,3,6]
l2 = []
a = l.index(6)
l2.append(a)
print(l2)
```

Saída

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esta questão você vai precisar implementar um laço de repetição e percorrer a tal lista com ajuda da função enumerate().

Seguindo esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
l = [1, 6, 6, 2, 3, 6]
l2 = list()
for indice, item in enumerate(l):
    if item == 6:
        l2.append(indice)

print(l2)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código o laço **for** percorrerá toda a lista **l** e com a ajuda da função **enumerate** verificará os índices dos respectivos elementos. E, caso o referido elemento tiver valor **6**, o índice do mesmo será adicionado à lista **l2**. E, em seguida, a lista **l2** será exibida.

A saída será:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizar **List Comprehensio**. Neste caso o código poderia ficar com apenas **1** linha de código. O código seria:

```
print([indice for indice, item in enumerate([1, 6, 6, 2, 3, 6]) if item == 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma lista diretamente utilizando list comprehension:

```
l = [1,6,6,2,3,6]
l2 = [ i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] == 6 ]
```

Verificamos por índice se o 6 esta contido, caso esteja adicionamos o índice a lista.
Neste caso não existe a necessidade de utilizar o **enumerate**.

Sua saída será:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é construir um dicionário que armazena nas chaves os itens distintos da lista de entrada e nos valores uma lista com índices de ocorrência de suas respectivas chaves na lista de entrada e então pesquisar por um item.

O algoritmo usa duas funções:

1. `indexar_correncias(t)` que aceita como parâmetro `t`, uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

   - Cria um dicionário vazio `resultado`.
   - Cria uma [enumeração](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) sobre `t` e para cada elemento `e` nessa enumeração:

     - Verifica se existe a chave `e[1]` em `resultado`:

       - Se existir, ao valor da chave `e[1]` é apensado `e[0]`.
       - Se não existir, é criada em `resultado` a chave `e[1]` e o seu valor é uma lista contendo `e[0]`.
     - Retorna o `resultado`.
2. `ocorrencias(s , item)` que aceita como parâmetro `s`, uma [sequência](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), e `item` um inteiro:

   - Converte a sequência `s` em uma *tupla* e a passa como argumento para função `indexar_correncias()` que retorna em `o` o dicionário cujos os valores são listas com índices de ocorrência de suas respectivas chaves em `s`.
   - Verifica se em `o` existe a chave `item`:

     - Caso exista retorna o valor `o[item]` cuja é lista dos indices das aparições de `item` em `s`.
     - Caso não exista retorna uma lista vazia.

Exemplo:

```
from functools import lru_cache 
#from random import chooices                          #<-- Descomente a linha caso faça o teste a seguir.

l = [1,6,6,2,3,6]
#l = [c for c in choices(range(1, 100), k=1000000)]   #<-- Teste também o algoritmo com uma entrada mais robusta.


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)                      #Informa que a função será cacheada
def indexar_correncias(t):
    resultado = {}                            #Cria um dicionário vazio
    #Para cada elemento e em enumerate(t)...
    for e in enumerate(t):
        #Verifica se existe a chave e[1] em resultado...
        if e[1] in resultado:
            resultado[e[1]].append(e[0])      #Se existir, ao valor da chave e[1] é apensado e[0].
        else:
           resultado[e[1]] = [e[0]]           #Se não existir, é criada em resultado a chave e[1].
    return resultado                          #Retorna o resultado.
    
def ocorrencias(s , item):
    o = indexar_correncias(tuple(s))          #retorna em o o dicionário cujos os valores são listas com índices de ocorrência de suas respectivas chaves em s.
    #Verifica se em o existe a chave item
    if item in o:
        return o[item]                        #Caso exista retorna o valor o[item].
    return []                                 #Retorna uma lista vazia.
    
while True:
    s = input("Digite um numero para buscar os seus indices: ")
    if s.isnumeric():
        print(ocorrencias( l, int(s)))
    elif s == "":
        break
```

<sup>Teste no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/yKJX0b)</sup>

A linha `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` é um decorador para embrulhar uma função em um chamável [memoizável](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) ou seja uma vez que função seja executada com determinado argumento é criado uma cache em memória armazenado o resultado da função para aquele argumento e então a cada vez que a função é chamada com esse mesmo argumento ao invés de refazer todos os operação e iterações pelo argumento ela busca no cache o resultado.
Para entradas pequenas esse recurso é irrelevante porém para entradas volumosas de dados é um recurso essencial.
Na primeira chamada da função com um argumento não memoizado a [complexidade de tempo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo) da função é *O(n)*, após primeira chamada para um argumento a complexidade de tempo da função é *O(1)*.

`indexar_correncias()` é alimentada com *tupla* pois um dos requisitos para o [`lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) funcionar é que os parâmetros da função memoizada sejam [hasheáveis](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.9/glossary.html) e em python apenas objetos imutáveis são hasheáveis e tuplas são sequencias imutáveis.